# Using NSPredicate to filter an NSArray based on NSDictionary keys

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have an array of dictionaries.

I want to filter the array based on a key.

I tried this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SPORT ==  %@)", @"Football"];

NSArray *filteredArray = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

This doesn't work, I get no results. I think I'm doing something wrong. I know this is the method if "SPORT" was an ivar. I think it is probably different if it is a key.

I haven't been able to find an example however.

Thanks

---

**Update**

I added quotes around the string I am searching for.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SPORT ==  '%@')", @"Football"];
```

It still does not work.

---

**Update 2**

Solved it. I actually had to remove the single quotes, which seems to go against what the guide says.

My real problem is I had a nested array and I wasn't actually evaluating the dictionaries. Bone head move.

Comment: Just to mention that the predicate is case sensitive by default (use [c] to get unsensitive).

Comment: possible duplicate of [ios sorting array of dictionaries by key of inner dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509138/ios-sorting-array-of-dictionaries-by-key-of-inner-dictionary)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

It should work - as long as the data variable is actually an array containing a dictionary with the key SPORT

```
NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"foo" forKey:@"BAR"]];    
NSArray *filtered = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(BAR == %@)", @"foo"]];
```

Filtered in this case contains the dictionary.

(the %@ does not have to be quoted, this is done when NSPredicate creates the object.)

Comment: Does NSPredicate work on the iPhone? It works great on the sim but running it on the iPhone gives an error that the NSPredicate class could not be found.

Comment: NSPredicate is available since iOS 3.0.

Comment: to clarify for new coders like me, the key line of code is 'NSArray *filtered = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(BAR == %@)", @"foo"]];' where 'data' is the nsarray of nsdictionaries that is already in your code. (thank you suraken)

Comment: What if the key names are dynamic?

Answer (score 27):

I know it's old news but to add my two cents. By default I use the commands `LIKE[cd]` rather than just `[c]`. The `[d]` compares letters with accent symbols. This works especially well in my Warcraft App where people spell their name "Vòódòó" making it nearly impossible to search for their name in a tableview. The `[d]` strips their accent symbols during the predicate. So a predicate of `@"name LIKE[CD] %@", object.name` where `object.name == @"voodoo"` will return the object containing the name Vòódòó.

From the Apple documentation:
like[cd] means “case- and diacritic-insensitive like.”) For a complete description of the string syntax and a list of all the operators available, see [***Predicate Format String Syntax***](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).

Answer (score 11):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
// clang -framework Foundation Siegfried.m 
    int
main() {
    NSArray *arr = @[
        @{@"1" : @"Fafner"},
        @{@"1" : @"Fasolt"}
    ];
    NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
        @"SELF['1'] CONTAINS 'e'"];
    NSArray *res = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
    NSLog(@"Siegfried %@", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`NSPredicate` is only available in iPhone 3.0.

You won't notice that until try to run on device.

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 3, when you want to filter an array of dictionaries with a predicate based on dictionary keys and values, you may choose one of the following patterns.

---

#### #1. Using `NSPredicate` [`init(format:arguments:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspredicate/1417368-init) initializer

If you come from Objective-C, `init(format:arguments:)` offers a key-value coding style to evaluate your predicate.

Usage:

```
import Foundation

let array = [["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"], ["key1": "value3"], ["key3": "value4"]]

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "key1 == %@", "value1")
//let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self['key1'] == %@", "value1") // also works
let filteredArray = array.filter(predicate.evaluate)

print(filteredArray) // prints: [["key2": "value2", "key1": "value1"]]
```

---

#### #2. Using `NSPredicate` [`init(block:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspredicate/1416182-init) initializer

As an alternative if you prefer *strongly typed* APIs over *stringly typed* APIs, you can use `init(block:)` initializer.

Usage:

```
import Foundation

let array = [["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"], ["key1": "value3"], ["key3": "value4"]]

let dictPredicate = NSPredicate(block: { (obj, _) in
    guard let dict = obj as? [String: String], let value = dict["key1"] else { return false }
    return value == "value1"
})

let filteredArray = array.filter(dictPredicate.evaluate)
print(filteredArray) // prints: [["key2": "value2", "key1": "value1"]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the [NSPredicate reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795), it looks like you need to surround your substitution character with quotes. For example, your current predicate reads: `(SPORT == Football)` You want it to read `(SPORT == 'Football')`, so your format string needs to be `@"(SPORT == '%@')"`.

Comment: I thought thats what it said, too. Apparently the quotes aren't needed. I'm not sure exactly what the guide is saying quotes "should" be used for.