# NSPredicate on NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I'm trying to make sections in a table view based on the alphabet and sort my entries alphabetically under these sections.

I have collected the first letter in every entry of bandsArray in bandsArrayIndex and I'm now trying to use NSPredicate to count how many of each letter there are.

I'm doing this by following [this guide](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43374).

They are using an NSArray and I'm using an NSDictionary and can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone help me out?

The application crashes when trying to show the view with the table view in it.
In Debugger Console the following error is shown:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'Can't do a substring operation with
>   something that isn't a string

This is my code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *alphabet = [bandsArrayIndex objectAtIndex:section];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
    NSArray *letters = [bandsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    return [letters count];
}
```

EDIT: This is my bandsArray.

The header

```
NSMutableArray *bandsArray;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* bandsArray;
```

The implementation

```
// set array from plist
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Bands" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray* tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

self.bandsArray = tmpArray;

// sort array after name ascending
NSSortDescriptor *nameSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
[bandsArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSorter]];
```

Comment: Can you show your bandsArray ? Is it just a NSString array ?
I had no such problems with NSPredicate. It should be just a simple detail. If your bandsArray is not of NSStrings, you should filter by the property you're looking for.

Comment: You're leaking memory like a sieve when you create `bandsArray`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do you mean that `bandsArray` is an array of dictionaries?  If so, and assuming each dictionary has a `name` key, you should be able to change the predicate to something like `@"SELF.name beginswith[c] %@"`.

If, on the other hand, `bandsArray` is actually a dictionary itself, maybe you want to do `[[bandsArray allKeys] filteredArrayUsingPredicate...]`.

Comment: `@"SELF.name beginswith[c] %@"` did the trick! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
// clang -framework Foundation Siegfried.m 
    int
main() {
    NSArray *arr = @[
        @{@"1" : @"Fafner"},
        @{@"1" : @"Fasolt"}
    ];
    NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF['1'] CONTAINS 'e'"];
    NSArray *res = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
    NSLog(@"Siegfried %@", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank @isaak it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didnt notice you had a NSArray of NSDictionaries.

Read this thread: [Using NSPredicate to filter an NSArray based on NSDictionary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958622/using-nspredicate-to-filter-an-nsarray-based-on-nsdictionary-keys)

When you use NSDictionary, you should check by its Key... I'm not sure you're using the right approach!

I would do something like:
@implementation Word : NSObect {
    NSString *title;
}

then I would create a NSArray of Words and filter on them with:
@"title beginswith[c] %@"