# JSON Parsing : Retrieving data from the NSDictionary and storing it in an array

Tags: ios, json, parsing, nsdictionary

```
{
    Address =     (
                {
            address = "Bengaluru, Karnataka 560008, India";
            "address_id" = 29;
            "address_title" = "";
            "building_name" = "";
            latitude = "23.95579108";
            longitude = "77.64169808";
            "user_id" = 13;
        },
                {
            address = "Bengaluru, Karnataka 560008, India";
            "address_id" = 31;
            "address_title" = "";
            "building_name" = "";
            latitude = "22.95578162";
            longitude = "77.64173089";
            "user_id" = 13;
        },
                {
            address = "Bengaluru, Karnataka 560008, India";
            "address_id" = 37;
            "address_title" = "";
            "building_name" = "";
            latitude = "22.95577373";
            longitude = "77.64173507";
            "user_id" = 13;
        },
                  {
            address = "256, Road Number 19, Wadla Village, Vadala, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400031, India";
            "address_id" = 49;
            "address_title" = dsa;
            "building_name" = das;
            latitude = "19.01761470";
            longitude = "72.85616440";
            "user_id" = 13;
        }
    );
}
```

I'm trying to retrive data from the JSON dictionary.
I need to fetch the datas in address from the Address dictionary and store it in an array . 
My Array should look like this :
[Bengaluru, Karnataka 560008, India,Bengaluru, Karnataka 560008, India,Bengaluru, Karnataka 560008, India,256, Road Number 19, Wadla Village, Vadala, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400031, India]

Need help please .

Comment: Have you checked the nsjsonserialization Class and it's methods?

Comment: Well, wouldn't you just create an NSMutableArray and add to it whatever you want from the dictionary?

Comment: As I can see,Your JSON array is not correct. double quotes are missing for address and semicolon shouldn't  be there in JSON Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];   
NSError *jsonError = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSDictionary *pR = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourJsonObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];
NSArray *pArray = pR[@"Address"];

for(NSDictionary *dict in pR)
{
    [resultArray addObject:dict[@"address"]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jad . But still its not working infact its crashing with nil value .

Comment: Where is it crashing ?
try to log pR, pArray and dict.
let me know what happens

Comment: [resultArray addObject:dict[@"address"]];
resultArray returns nil

Comment: Can you log dict[@"address"] inside the loop and tell me what u get ??

Comment: no problem anytime :D, just submit the answer as valid so people know u got answered :D

Answer (score 0):

[Filtering NSDictionary with predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556905/filtering-nsdictionary-with-predicate)

You can filter an NSDictionary with an NSPredicate.

Assuming your dictionary is `NSDictionary *dict`

```
NSArray *resultArray = [[dict objectForKey:@"Address" allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(key == %@)", @"address"]];
```