# Filter a NSMutableArray of objects and copy to a new NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a NSObject defined with a few properties and to keep this question simple, let's say the object is called Vehicle and there are three properties: Manufacturer, Model, Year.

I read all vehicles from a database and the result is a NSMutableArray of Vehicle objects.

I am trying to create a new array of vehicles that are filtered by manufacturer where the object = "Ford".

Is the correct approach:

```
NSPredicate *fordMotorCarsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY   Vehicle.Manufacturer = %@", @"Ford"];

fordMotorCarsArray = [listOfVehicles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fordMotorCarsPredicate];
```

I know I could filter the list using an SQL query, but I'd like to know whether this can be achieved in Objective-C code.

Any ideas?
Cheers,
Ross.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using NSPredicate to filter an NSArray based on NSDictionary keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958622/using-nspredicate-to-filter-an-nsarray-based-on-nsdictionary-keys)

Comment: Yes, I have. Program is crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each object in the mutable array has a `manufacturer` property then predicate should be

```
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"manufacturer = %@", @"Ford"];
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the easiest solution. Appreciate all the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a predicate only if the underlying objects are KVC-compliant for the key you are testing against. But that condition is actually a weak condition. It's enough for example to have a property by that name.

Now you can always filter your array manually:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) cars:(NSArray *)listOfVehicles builtBuy:(NSString*)manufacturer {
    NSMutableArray *resultCars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (Car *aCar in listOfVehicles) {
        if ([manufacturer isEqualToString:aCar.Manufacturer]) {
            [resultCars addObject:aCar];
        }
    }
    return [resultCars autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ther is an alternative to NSPredicat but i'm not sure it's worth it in your case... sow
  this is how you sort an array alfabetically,

```
somearray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:an array]; 

     NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
     sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Vehicle" ascending:YES] autorelease];
     [somearray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

however if you need a more specific sorting you can add a selector to the sort descriptor that will hold the logic of the sorting like this

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Vehicle" ascending:NO selector:@selector(VehicleSortingLogic:)];

I never used it with a selector before but it should work , hope this helps