# NSMutableArray and NSPredicate filtering

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am trying to filter my array with two entities within an object like I have a Person object in which I have name, address, number, email, etc. I am trying to filter my array list of objects with just name and number. How can this be achieved with using NSPredicate?

Comment: I think [here is a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958622/using-nspredicate-to-filter-an-nsarray-based-on-nsdictionary-keys).

Comment: What have you tried already? What happened? Have you checked the documentation or examples on the web? Did you search stackoverflow for similar questions? Did you have trouble understanding them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create the predicate (the following assumes that your `Person` class has `name` and `number` string properties):

```
NSString *nameFilter = @"Steve*";
NSString *numberFilter = @"555-*";
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name like %@) or (number like %@)", nameFilter, numberFilter];
```

Then, filter the array (this assumes you have an `NSArray` of `Person` objects):

```
NSArray *personArray = /* obtain from somewhere */;
NSArray *filtered = [personArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

The result will be an array that contains `Person` objects whose `name` could be “Steve”, “Steven” etc, and whose number starts with `555-`.

#### Edit

What you're saying doesn't really make sense. You can't remove properties from a class (or rather, you *shouldn't*). If you just want an array that contains only the names and numbers you'll have to iterate through the array of `Person` objects:

```
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

for (Person *p in personArray)
    [result addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%@ : %@", [p name], [p number]]];
```

Comment: what if I don't want to use name like but I want all the names and numbers, then how do I set my predicate filter?

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I think you can't do that similarly with nspredicate? Just curious if thats possible.

Comment: @kforkarim: Predicates are used to determine whether an object matches a set of rules or not, they aren't for transforming one object into another.

Comment: @kforkarim: If this is exactly what you were looking for, why did you accept the other answer?

Comment: because both answers are correct one way or another, just a different approach.

Comment: should be `for(NSObject* o in arr){...}` not `foreach`

Comment: @BDR: correct - I was probably confusing it for C#.

Answer (score 4):

i believe you are looking for:

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name==%@",name];
```

or if you want similarities for string names you could also use:

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like %@",name];
```

and assuming phone number is just an int, you could use ==, <, <=, etc for number comparisons

then apply it with:

```
NSArray * filteredarray  = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: The thing is, if I do the way above, it will just list the array based on that name, but I want to delete all the rest of the entities and display just two entity. Guess I have to iterate through the for loop for that.

Comment: NSPredicate will remove all non matching entries from the array. It won't delete them from the array but it will return a second filtered array with just the objects that match the predicate

Comment: @kforkarim NSArray are immutable you can't delete items in them. Every method that would change an NSArray, will return a new array. If you are using NSMutableArray it's an other story, but here I don't think NSMutableArray are needed, you just need to take the return array and work with it.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `CONTAINS` word to do filtering. It's easy to do this job. Or you can combine them together:

```
NSPredicate * predicate =
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR name LIKE[cd] %@", filterName, filterName];
```

You can refer to [OFFICIAL DOC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795):

> BEGINSWITH: The left-hand expression begins with the right-hand expression.
>
> CONTAINS: The left-hand expression contains the right-hand expression.
>
> ENDSWITH: The left-hand expression ends with the right-hand expression.
>
> LIKE: The left hand expression equals the right-hand expression: ? and * are allowed as wildcard characters, where ? matches 1 character and * matches 0 or more characters.
>
> MATCHES: The left hand expression equals the right hand expression using a regex-style comparison according to ICU v3 (for more details see the ICU User Guide for Regular Expressions).

Comment: On an unrelated note, please don't [approve suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2763311) using backticks for emphasis, but reject or improve them - see e.g. [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88) why

Answer (score 0):

```
NSPredicate *pNewsCard = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"feedType = %@", @"NewsCard"];

NSArray *filteredNewsCard = [arrayTotalFeed filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pNewsCard];
```

`feedType` is the property of a Custom object to be compared and `arrayTotalFeed` is the array of Custom objects.