# NSMutableArray filter objects using NSPredicate issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have NSMutableArray with music files objects in .mp3 format. All items fetched from document directory. My problem is I am getting .sqlite files along with .mp3 files. **I want only .mp3 files from NSMutableArray.** I tried with NSPredicate but it giving me error of Incompatible pointer types NSMutableArray/NSArray.([NSMutableArray and NSPredicate filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436496/nsmutablearray-and-nspredicate-filtering))

I don't want files like (projectname.sqlite,projectname.sqlite-shm,projectname.sqlite-val etc)

My code is,

```
downloadedFilesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

fileManger = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
downloadedFilesArray = [[fileManger contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:fileDest error:&error] mutableCopy];

if([downloadedFilesArray containsObject:@".DS_Store"])
    [downloadedFilesArray removeObject:@".DS_Store"];
```

How to filter files like .mp3,.m3u,.aac??

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Anyway, the NSPredicate should work, but you can write the filtering logic by yourself:

```
NSMutableArray* downloadedFilesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* removeFilesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString* fileName in downloadedFilesArray){
    if ([fileName.lowercaseString rangeOfString:@".mp3"].location != fileName.length - 4) {
         [removeFilesArray addObject:fileName];
    }
}
[downloadedFilesArray removeObjectsInArray:removeFilesArray];
```

Comment: Helpful. What if I have extensions in .MP3 and .mp3. Yes I am talking about case sensitivity. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSString`'s `pathExtension` to get the file extension, if any, or use an `NSPredicate`. Also, remember to check if there is an `NSError` when retrieving the contents of the directory.

```
NSMutableArray *mp3DownloadedFilesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *targetFileExtension = @"mp3";

NSError *error;
NSArray *allDownloadedFilesArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:fileDest error:&error];

if (allDownloadedFilesArray && allDownloadedFilesArray.count > 0 && !error) {
    for (NSString* fileName in allDownloadedFilesArray) {
        if ([fileName.pathExtension compare:targetFileExtension options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
            [mp3DownloadedFilesArray addObject:fileName];
        }
    }
} else {
    // Process the error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `filterUsingPredicate:` method:

```
[downloadedFilesArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH %@", @".mp3"]];
```

Or for case-insensitive version:

```
[downloadedFilesArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH [cd] %@", @".mp3"]];
```

EDIT: if you want to filter with more file extension, you can create multiple `NSPredicates` (one for each extension) and combine them using `[NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates]`. Sorry but I won't provide the ready-to-use solution, you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *downloadedFilesArray = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil]; 

// filter the array for only sqlite files  

NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.mp3' || "]; 
NSArray *sqliteFiles = [allFiles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
```