# Filter array using predicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to filter following array with **status** equal to **"U"** and i have used following.

```
 NSArray *result = [alertModified.senders filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(subscriptions.status = %@)",@"U"]];
```

But I'm getting empty arrays.

Please help me on filtering this?

Array String:

```
(senderCode =  CPFB, senderName = CPFB, forSenderLevel = 0, subscriptions = (
"correspondenceListId = 102,status = S,senderCode = AA,subject = Letter,retentionPeriod = 0, uniqueBillIdentifier = (null),senderResponseStatus = (null),subscriptionDate = ,effectiveDate = ",
"correspondenceListId = 103,status = U,senderCode = BB,subject = Nomination Letters,retentionPeriod = 0, uniqueBillIdentifier = (null),senderResponseStatus = (null),subscriptionDate = ,effectiveDate = ",
"correspondenceListId = 104,status = U,senderCode = AA,subject = Yearly statements,retentionPeriod = 0, uniqueBillIdentifier = (null),senderResponseStatus = (null),subscriptionDate = ,effectiveDate = ",
"correspondenceListId = 105,status = U,senderCode = BB,subject = All Future Letters,retentionPeriod = 0, uniqueBillIdentifier = (null),senderResponseStatus = (null),subscriptionDate = ,effectiveDate = "))
```

Comment: So,you need to sort **subscriptions**,or the whole string somehow?

Comment: Is that an array of comma separated strings?

Comment: I don't need to sort but i need to filter out record which has status is "U", i.e. i should get only 3 record from above. Above string is representation of Object hierarchy.

Comment: see this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958622/using-nspredicate-to-filter-an-nsarray-based-on-nsdictionary-keys

Comment: Thanks Piyush, "==" didn't work and your link is sample of one level array.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you should be filtering the subscription list itself, not the whole senders. You have to apply the filter to each sender. Try changing your filter line to this and check if it gives you results:

```
 NSArray *result = [[alertModified.senders objectAtIndex:0].subscriptions filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(status = %@)",@"U"]];
```

Comment: Thanks Angel. But i want to iterate over nested Arrays, not within one arrays. Your code snippet filter within single list.