# Retrieve NSDictionary from NSArray where dictionary key has value X

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSArray` with `NSDictionaries`. One of the dictionaries keys in one of the arrays contains a value. I want to retrieve the `NSDictionary` with that value.

My array:

```
Array: (
        {
        DisplayName = "level";
        InternalName = "Number 2";
        NumberValue = 1;
    },
        {
        DisplayName = "PurchaseAmount";
        InternalName = "Number 1";
        NumberValue = 3500;
    }
)
```

So, I would like to get the dictionary which contains `DisplayName` set to `PurchaseAmount` (case insensitive).

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: You should be able to use `NSPredicate` for that.  [See similar example here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/958622/119114).

Comment: Thnx for the tip. I'll add the solution I used to the answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following solved my problem:

```
NSArray *filtered = [promotions filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(DisplayName == %@)", @"PurchaseAmount"]];
NSDictionary *item = [filtered objectAtIndex:0];
```

Thnx to user Nate for his comment on my question!

Comment: Actually, both this answer, and [especially lindinax's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15831638/119114) are better than the one you accepted.  Bhargavi's answer checks that a key *contains* the string, but your question asked for a result with a key equal to a certain value.  In general, those two aren't the same thing.  It may not make a difference for your key names, but for others it very well could.

Comment: You are answering your own question wrong as you asked for "case insensitive". Especially as you set it as the accepted one.

Comment: @lindinax fair enough. I think the reason I chose my answer before yours is mostly because I posted it before you posted yours. But, you are correct and I changed it now, 5 years later ;)

Answer (score 9):

LIKE[cd] will also do it

```
NSArray *filtered = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(DisplayName LIKE[cd] %@)", @"purchaseAmount"]];
```

returned

```
<NSArray>(
    {
       DisplayName = PurchaseAmount;
       InternaName = "Number 1";
       NumberValue = 3500;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `NSPredicate` this way

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"DisplayName LIKE[cd] 'PurchaseAmount' "];
NSArray *filter = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@",filter);
```

Here filter will hold your dictionaries which contains DisplayName set to PurchaseAmount (case insensitive)

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Better then my newly found solution.

Comment: Actually, this is **not** what the question asked.  Your predicate finds matches where the key **contains** the string.   If there's another key that is a superset of this key name, your filter gives a *false positive*. (e.g. `DisplayName = "PurchaseAmountWithTax"`;)

Comment: You are right, even though Bhargavi's solution sure is usefull!

Answer (score 3):

Answer in Swift,

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] %@", stringLookingFor)
let newList = data .filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
```

The data nsarray looks like this

```
[
 {
   name = Carlos,
   total = 9
 },
 {
   name = Willy,
   total = 2
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"DisplayName == 'level'"];
  NSArray *arrOutput = [[Array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
```

with the help of above 2 lines you will get all dictionary with DisplayName = "PurchaseAmount"