# How to find key in a NSDictionary object array ios

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have a `NSMutableArray`like this.

```
[
 {
  "Employee": {
  "EmployeeCode": 17125,
  "DisplayName": "MI0000026 - ABC",
  "DisplayName2": "ABC2",
  "Initials": "W. S. S.",
  "Surname": "CCC",
  "FirstName": "ABC",
  "MiddleName": "CDE",
  "LastName": "",
  "FullName": "ABC EMPLOYEE",

},
"LeaveDetail": {
  "LeaveDetailId": 21,
  "LeaveEntryCode": 16,
  "RequestId": 20,
  "EmployeeCode": 17125,
  "LeaveYear": 2016,
  "LeaveTypeCode": 1,
  "BaseType": "ess",
  "LeaveDate": "2016-09-05T00:00:00",
}
}
]
```

there are several objects in this array which has these kind of dictionaries. I want to find all the objects in this array which has `"LeaveDate": "2016-09-05T00:00:00"` this LeaveDate key is inside the `LeaveDetail` dictionary. How can I find all the objects which has LeaveDate as "2016-09-05T00:00:00"

**EDIT**
`NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"LeaveDate CONTAINS[cd] %@",dm.strClickedDate];`

But, I don't get any result.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve NSDictionary from NSArray where dictionary key has value X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831183/retrieve-nsdictionary-from-nsarray-where-dictionary-key-has-value-x)

Comment: Please search before posting.

Comment: It's not the same,, mine has 2 types of objects,, and I have already tried this  like this. NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"LeaveDate CONTAINS[cd] %@",dm.strClickedDate]; butI dont get any result.Thats why I posted this

Comment: You should have added that to your question.  We don't magically know what you have and haven't tried if you don't tell us.  Also use the correct data type, which for that entry is `NSDate`, not `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictonary *dict = [yourMutableArray[0]];//get dict in array with index = 0
NSLog(@"%@",dict);
//*Log dict will show:
 {
  "Employee": {
  "EmployeeCode": 17125,
  "DisplayName": "MI0000026 - ABC",
  "DisplayName2": "ABC2",
  "Initials": "W. S. S.",
  "Surname": "CCC",
  "FirstName": "ABC",
  "MiddleName": "CDE",
  "LastName": "",
  "FullName": "ABC EMPLOYEE",

},
"LeaveDetail": {
  "LeaveDetailId": 21,
  "LeaveEntryCode": 16,
  "RequestId": 20,
  "EmployeeCode": 17125,
  "LeaveYear": 2016,
  "LeaveTypeCode": 1,
  "BaseType": "ess",
  "LeaveDate": "2016-09-05T00:00:00",
}
}
*//
NSDictionay *leaveDetailDict = [dict objectForKey:@"LeaveDetail"];//get dict have key LeaveDetail
NSLog(@"%@",leaveDetailDict[@"LeaveDate"];
```