# Selecting dictionaries from JSON

Tags: json, cocoa-touch, dictionary

My app is connecting to an external database and downloading JSON data. The Data is stored in an array of dictionaries with each one representing a user profile.

There is a key in every dictionary that displays if they are visible or invisible.
The value of this key is either 1 or 0.

I want to pass only the "visible" profiles into a tableview. The visible profiles are represented by a 1 in the "active" key.

Basically I want to loop through the main dictionary array and create a new array of dictionaries that contains only dictionaries that have that key value.

anyone know the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html). There's an example [here](http://theocacao.com/document.page/346). Here's an answer which filters dictionaries in an array: [Using NSPredicate to filter an NSArray based on NSDictionary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958622/using-nspredicate-to-filter-an-nsarray-based-on-nsdictionary-keys).