# How to use the NSPredicate for searching a string inside the array in dictionary, in array of dictionaries?

Tags: ios, nspredicate

Hi I have a Array like this:

```
@[
    @{@"Name":@"marko"; @"ids"=@[@"121",@"156",@"175",@"154"];},
    @{@"Name":@"shine";@"ids"=@[@"175",@"165",@"154",@"187"];},
    @{@"Name":@"David";@"ids"=@[@"857",@"297",@"156",@"254"];},
    @{@"Name":@"Harry"; @ids"=@[@"297",@"154",@"867",@"201"];},
];
```

How to get the dictionaries having the string `@"156"` in the `ids` array using an NSPredicate.

Comment: Have a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958622/using-nspredicate-to-filter-an-nsarray-based-on-nsdictionary-keys

Comment: I Worked like this but i didn't get the result what i want . if "array" is the mainArray.   
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ids == %@",@"156"];
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; 
But it shows 0 count .Please Give Suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = @{@"Name": @"marko", @"ids" : @[@"121",@"156",@"175",@"154"]};
NSDictionary *dict2 = @{@"Name":@"shine", @"ids" : @[@"175",@"165",@"154",@"187"]};
NSDictionary *dict3 = @{@"Name":@"David", @"ids" : @[@"857",@"297",@"156",@"254"]};
NSDictionary *dict4 = @{@"Name":@"Harry", @"ids" : @[@"297",@"154",@"867",@"201"]};

NSArray *test = @[dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4];

NSArray *filtered = [test filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ids CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"156"]];
```