# How to fetch JSON data in to auto-complete text field in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying to make a country and state textfield auto-complete and I have all records the in JSON from a server database, but I don't know how to call the JSON inside Xcode and assign to the autocomplete textfield.

How can I consult this data when the user is typing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a long process,

Go step by step:

1. Fetch all data from your server
2. Parse those data in your understanding form (`NSArray` or `NSDictionary` or whatever you like.)
3. If you're using a simple `UITextField` then you should get notify if user is typing inside it. You can get this inside its delegate. `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {...}`
4. You may require to use a `NSPredicate` to filter data from the array (Generated in step-2). You may require to use a `like` format with it. [Using NSPredicate to filter an NSArray based on NSDictionary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958622/using-nspredicate-to-filter-an-nsarray-based-on-nsdictionary-keys)
5. You will also require to have some flag `isSearching` (or something you prefer), set it to `YES` if you found that data.
6. Reload your table.
7. If you're good to code then you will have some data which looks like autocomplete.
8. If not succeed then, check each steps in detail and find your problem.

At last, you can take reference from this [site](https://www.raywenderlich.com/336/auto-complete-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values) as well, good to start. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much Hemang for your great suggestion but i m beginner so i could not get the steps. could you please share any example if availble?.

Comment: Example is already included. Please check the last line of the answer.

Comment: Okay Thanks Hemang