# Search NSArray of NSDictionary. How to find using NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have an `NSArray`. It has one or more `NSDictionary` in each index. Based on the search input, I want to check whether it contain the value in `contact_Label` inside `contact_detail` dictionary. It will look like this:

```
(
  {
     "contact_detail" =     {
          "contact_is_in_phone" = 1;
          "contact_Label" = "Tyler Globussoft";
          "contact_displayname" = "Suzan Arohh";
     },
     "last_msg_details" =     {
           .....
     };
  },
  {
  }
);
```

I have tired like this. But not getting the result.

```
NSArray *contacts = self.dataArray; //your array of NSDictionary objects
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contact_Label = %@",stringValue];
NSArray *filteredContacts = [contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

Comment: `@"contact_detail.contact_Label = %@"`?

Comment: As @Larme mentioned, try Cocoa's [Key Value Coding (KVC)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using NSPredicate to filter an NSArray based on NSDictionary keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958622/using-nspredicate-to-filter-an-nsarray-based-on-nsdictionary-keys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
NSArray *contacts = self.dataArray; //your array of NSDictionary objects
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contact_detail.contact_Label = %@",stringValue];
NSArray *filteredContacts = [contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

Happy coding...