# Using NSPredicate to filter an NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries to find if a "key" exists

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have an NSMutableArray of dictionaries. I am using NSPredicate to filter through the array to find if a dictionary with a particular key exists or not.

I have referred to various examples, one of the closest is here: [Using NSPredicate to filter an NSArray based on NSDictionary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958622/using-nspredicate-to-filter-an-nsarray-based-on-nsdictionary-keys). However, I don't wish to have a value to the key. My problem is that I want to find the key first. I tried different syntaxes, but it did not help.

What I have done so far:

```
    NSString *key = @"open_house_updated_endhour";
    NSPredicate *predicateString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K", key];
    //NSPredicate *predicateString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains [cd]", key]; Doesn't work.
    //NSPredicate *predicateString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", key]; Won't work because it expects a value here.
    NSLog(@"predicate %@",predicateString);
    NSArray *filtered = [updatedDateAndTime filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; // updatedDateAndTime is the NSMutableArray
```

Comment: so you just want to know if "a certain key" is present in the dictionaries contained in an array or not?

Comment: @AdeelMiraj Yes, exactly! That's what I want.

Comment: In my opinion enumerating the array would be relatively easier and straight forward way to do this. Is there any particular reason for doing doing this through predicates?

Comment: @AdeelMiraj... The reason why I am doing this is because I have redundant logic for various cells in the table view. Hence, I don't want to increase my code logic unnecessary. Also, as I am new to iOS, I wanted to use the available NSPredicate system to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dictionary delivers `nil` as value for absent key. So simply compare the key against `nil`.

```
NSPredicate *predicateString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K==NULL", key]; // Dictionaries not having the key
NSPredicate *predicateString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K!=NULL", key]; // Dictionaries having the key
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick help. It helped. I get an array with the required dictionary object, if it exists. What if I want to use @"%K == NULL" || @"%K != NULL" ? If I do this, I get an error. Basically, I would like to update the dictionary if the key is found. It does not matter, if it is empty or not. No doubt, I like this simple solution.

Comment: I do not understand, why you want to use `@"%K == NULL" || @"%K != NULL"`. First of all there is an extra `"` after the first `NULL`, what is an error. Can you tell me the error you get? However, the expression would always be true. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
 NSArray *Myarray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"my hello string" forKey:@"name"]];   
NSArray *filteredarray = [Myarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name == %@)", @"my hello string"]];
NSLog("%@",filteredarray);
```

Another example :

```
NSString *mycategory = @"iamsomeone";
NSArray *myitems = @[@{ @"types" : @[@"novel", @"iamsomeone", @"dog"] },
                   @{ @"types" : @[@"cow", @"iamsomeone-iam", @"dog"] },
                   @{ @"types" : @[@"cow", @"bow", @"cat"] }];
NSPredicate *mypredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    NSArray *categories = [evaluatedObject objectForKey:@"types"];
    return [categories containsObject:mycategory];
}];

NSArray *outpuArray = [myitems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:mypredicate];
NSLog(@"hello output:%@",outpuArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, the first example expects me to have a value for the key. In my case, it may or may not be there. Hence, I want to check for the key first.