# How get a key value in NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

A `NSMutableArray` called `arrayDB`, and it gets data from server by using `AFNetworking`, like this

```
  [self.arrayDB addObjectsFromArray:[responseObject objectForKey:@"list"]];
  NSLog(@"print:%@",self.arrayDB);
```

And the result like this.

```
  print:(
    {
    id = 10;
    key = 7707eca6ea4d2db923c8b7b4e6ec094c;
    },
    {
    id = 9;
    key = 7aaf962bc4df61a3b44c544c58fc6c82;
    },
    {
    id = 7;
    key = ce9d9e99a96d6417c6b34321c820c4c0;
    },
    {
    id = 6;
    key = 6086663465e5813d08f862eb443e2623;
    },
    {
    id = 4;
    key = 5d9519dd7de26f0139d6028fb83a4ead;
    }
   )
```

And now, I use sql statement to describe my needs, `select key from arrayDB where id=10`, how can I write in objective-C?

Comment: I hope this one is help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/958650/7306261

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSPredicate` like this:

```
NSArray *myArray = [self.arrayDB filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id == %@)", @"10"]];
```

Comment: The id in dictionary is of number type so the predicate would be:

`NSArray *myArray = [self.arrayDB filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id == %@)", @(10)]];`